# python exception handling

Tags: python

I am developing a Django site and have been having trouble trying to work out the best way to do exception handling. I have been doing

```
try:
    Some code
except:
    log error in my own words, i.e 'Some code' failed to execute
    Some other code
```

This catches all exceptions thus ensuring my site does not deliver 500 errors and such like. But, with my limited knowledge I am losing the actual exception and it is making it a real pain to debug. How do I print the error that occured? Currently I comment out try: catch: and see the error and fix it. There must be a better way!

Thanks in advance

Rich

Comment: Where have you seen the "naked" `except` statement like that?  Can you provide a quote or a link to a tutorial which shows this kind of programming?  It's considered to be a bad practice.  I want to know where you learned this.

Comment: @S.Lott: Instead of coming down on someone like that it might be better to offer some alternative approach and explain why it is considered bad practice.

Comment: @magiconair, I feel S.Lott is doing the Right Thing and is criticizing a tutorial author rather than OP. I have personally seen colleagues attempt to get "bare except" through code review multiple times, and I always educate them about the ugly consequences of ignoring KeyboardInterrupt, so the PR is improved prior to a merge.

Answer (score 25):

You catch the exception in an exception variable:

```
try:
    # some code
except Exception, e:
    # Log the exception.
```

There are various ways to format the exception, the logging module (which I assume you/Django uses) has support to format exceptions, and the exceptions themselves usually render useful messages when rendered to strings.

Here is an example:

```
import logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
logging.debug('This message should go to the log file')

try:    
    1/0
except Exception as e:
    logging.exception(e)
```

This example uses the new "as" syntax to catch the exception, supported in Python 2.6 and later. The output of the above is:

```
DEBUG:root:This message should go to the log file
ERROR:root:integer division or modulo by zero
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "untitled-1.py", line 6, in <module>
    1/0
ZeroDivisionError: integer division or modulo by zero
```

Answer (score 5):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys

try:
    0 / 0
except Exception, e:
    print >> sys.stderr, 'Hello %s' % e
    # Hello integer division or modulo by zero
```

Note that you can catch multiple exceptions for one block, e.g.:

```
try:
    open(filename)
except NameError, e:
    print >> sys.stderr, e
except IOError, ioe:
    print >> sys.stderr, ioe
```

More on exception handling can be found in this tutorial:

- http://docs.python.org/tutorial/errors.html

Answer (score 3):

this can help

```
try:

    raise Exception('spam', 'eggs')

except Exception as inst:

    print type(inst)     # the exception instance
    print inst.args      # arguments stored in .args
    print inst           # __str__ allows args to printed directly
    x, y = inst.args
    print 'x =', x
    print 'y =', y
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```python
try:
  # some code
except Exception, e:
  # log error with data from e
```

Answer (score 1):

[Django Middleware](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/middleware/?from=olddocs) is how you process exceptions in Django sites.

To catch all exceptions, you have to create a Django middleware and create a process_exception method.

```
from django.http import HttpResponse

class SomeMiddleware(object):
    def process_exception(self, request, exception):
        'Intercept exceptions'

        return HttpResponse('Hey! an error occurred',
                content_type='text/plain')
```

then you add it to your MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES setting:

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    # ...
    'some.module.SomeMiddleware',
)
```

Then you get control over what to do when encountering any kind of exception.

I think this answered your question. But you're probably better off [overriding the 500.html template or the handler500 view](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/views/#the-404-page-not-found-view). Notice that these views don't come into play until you set DEBUG to False in your project settings.