# How to catch specific Exception in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception

I want to catch a specific exception and present a message rather than the exception raise and breaking the code.

The exception is:

[The exception is: ICSharpCode.Decompiler.Metadata.PEFileNotSupportedException: PE file does not contain any managed metadata.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cc8bm.png)

I know where in the code the exception raises and that I should wrap it with try-except.
I don't know how to "Import" the specific exception and then use it properly in the code

I tried to build the exception like this:

```
class PEFileNotSupportedException(Exception):
    def __init__(self):
        super(PEFileNotSupportedException, self).__init__
```

and then import it and use it like that:

```
   try:
       os.system(command)
   except:
       raise PEFileNotSupportedException("The DDL of this type are NOT supported!!!")
```

But it is not working.

Comment: Please post the error as a text, not an image. And incapsulate it within "```" from both sides so it's formatted proparly

Comment: What have you written to *try* and address this issue?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [python exception handling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4592162/python-exception-handling)

Comment: Defining a new exception does not help you catch the *original* exception. You need to figure out which module exports the exception you want to catch.

Answer (score 0):

```
try:
  # your_code_here
except PEFileNotSupportedException:
  print('Your message here')
```

This should be what you are looking for, assuming you have imported PEFileNotSupportedException

With regards to importing the exception, it should be inside a module and you can import it with the "import" statement.

EDIT:
`from Module.Where.Your.Exception.Is import PEFileNotSupportedException`

Comment: from Module.Where.Your.Exception.Is

I imported it from the file where I created the class and it is not working

Answer (score 0):

You could try and import the exception with:

```
from ICSharpCode.Decompiler.Metadata import PEFileNotSupportedException

try:
    do_something()
except PEFileNotSupportedException:
    print("Exception caught")
```

Comment: Thanks, but there is no such module:
from ICSharpCode.Decompiler.Metadata import PEFileNotSupportedException
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ICSharpCode'