# is it possible to automate the Python scripts each time when returning an error?

Tags: python, automation

I want to automate the python to re-run the code when it returns error, is it possible and how can I do it?

I have a script and each time that returns an error I have to run it again. The error does not interfere in the process, so it can't be a problem re-run.

Comment: this got nothing with python but with the way you run it.

Comment: Why not use a `try - except` block to catch the error, and handle it that way?

Comment: It's seems a good idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you face an error, typically, the program will halt.
That's why there are [error handlers](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html) in place to not let that happen.

Look at some already answered examples [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4592193/15459230)

So, lets say you want the user to input integer values and it shouldn't halt, so you could use a loop and break it when the entered value is an integer (there's no error thrown)

```py
...
while True:
  try:
    i = int(input("Integer: "))
    break
  except:
    print("Error")
...
```

You get the idea.