# Skipping files if xml like part is missing

Tags: python, xml

I am analyzing the xml data of several files.
To get my data, I first need to split the xml data from the whole file to be able to work with it.

For this I use the `split()` method and search for `<Data`.

Here I run into a problem.

Some of the files have no xml data in them and therefore these files I would like to simply skip.

```py
path = r"C:\Users\Nathan\Desktop\Test\*.xml"

for xml in glob.glob(path):
    with open(xml) as data_file
        file_content = data_file.read

        xml_part1 = file_content.split("<Data",1)[1] #here i get an Error if "<Data" is not in the file In
        xml_part2 = file_content.split("Data>",1)[0]
        xml_file = "<Data" + xml_part2+"Data>"
```

For help I would be very grateful

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4592220/9296093

Comment: How about simple condition: `if '<Data' in file_content:`

Comment: Or use a regular expression `<Data.*?Data>` to get the XML portion of the file.

Comment: You're missing the `()` after `.read`

Comment: This is just horrible. Mixing XML and non-XML syntax in a single file is making your life really difficult. Much better to use XML for the whole thing - or at least embed it cleanly in some other language like JSON that you can parse with a proper parser.

Comment: *To get my data, I first need to split the xml data from the whole file to be able to work with it.* ... Why? Please provide more background as this post reads like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a try-catch block to catch the exception when the `split()` method fails because there is no xml data in that file.

```py
import glob

path = r"C:\Users\Nathan\Desktop\Test\*.xml"

for xml in glob.glob(path):
    with open(xml, 'r') as data_file:
        file_content = data_file.read()

        try:
            xml_part1 = file_content.split("<Data", 1)[1]
            xml_part2 = xml_part1.split("Data>", 1)[0]
            xml_data = "<Data" + xml_part2 + "Data>"
            
            # Do stuff with your xml data
            
        except IndexError:
            print(f"Skipping file {xml} as it does not contain <Data>")
```

Answer (score 1):

For future readers, avoid OP's treatment of XML as a regular text file and not as an encoded markup document with properties of elements and attributes. Consider using compliant DOM libraries such as Python's `etree` or `lxml` to parse relevant content.

Specifically, the XPath expression, `".//Data"`, can check this element in document with a logical test of [**`find`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html?highlight=find#xml.etree.ElementTree.ElementTree.find) for element existence or [**`findtext`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html?highlight=find#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element.findtext) for text existence.

```py
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import glob

path = r"C:\Users\Nathan\Desktop\Test\*.xml"

for xml in glob.glob(path):
    # PARSE DOCUMENT INTO XML TREE
    tree = ET.parse(xml)

    # SEARCH ELEMENT AND TEXT
    data_elem = tree.find(".//Data")
    data_text = tree.findtext(".//Data")

    if data_text is not None and data_text != "":
        # DO STUFF WITH PARSED Data ELEMENT TREE OR TEXT
        data_elem
        data_text
    else:
        print(f"Skipping file {xml} as it does not contain <Data>")
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a regexp to get the XML part of the file, then test if it matched anything.

```
import re ,glob

for xml in glob.glob(path):
    with open(xml, 'r') as data_file:
        file_content = data_file.read()
        match = re.search(r'<Data.*?Data>', file_content)
        if match:
            xml_data = match.group()
            # do stuff with xml_data
        else:
            print(f"Skipping file {xml} as it does not contain <Data>")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define a xsd and use `xmlschema`. As an example I have a valid and an invalid xml and a text file.

```
import xmlschema
from io import StringIO

dtat_xsd = """<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="Data">
  <xs:complexType>
  <xs:sequence>
  </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>"""
xsd = StringIO(dtat_xsd)

vali = """<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Data>
<others />
</Data>"""
f = StringIO(vali)

vali1 = """<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
</root>"""
f1 = StringIO(vali1)

tex = """Any text"""

schema = xmlschema.XMLSchema(xsd)
try:
    v = schema.is_valid(f)
    print(v)
    vf = schema.is_valid(f1)
    print(vf)
    te = schema.is_valid(tex)
    print(te)
except:
    print("EXCEPTION: Can't be parsed")
```

Output:

```
True
False
EXCEPTION: Can't be parsed
```